# azureiotedge-diagnostics from private Container Registry

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Is it possible to configure the container registry for the azureiotedge-diagnostics image download? I want to move azureiotedge-diagnostics image to a private container registry.

Comment: Did you look at this doc? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/production-checklist?view=iotedge-2020-11#store-runtime-containers-in-your-private-registry

Comment: Yes, I know it. But there is no documentation about the "azureiotedge-diagnostics" image. If I move the edgeHub and edgeAgent to a private container registry and use this images in the deployment.template.json is there also the "azureiotedge-diagnostics" image pulled from the private container registry?

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by [AshokPeddakotla-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188729/ashokpeddakotla-msft), along with storing your container images for custom code modules in your private Azure registry, you can also store public container images such as for the edgeAgent and edgHub runtime modules

Steps:

1. Get the image with Docker pull command

> Docker pull commands
>
> 1. [Azure IoT Edge Agent](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azureiotedge-agent) `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:<VERSION_TAG>`
> 2. [Azure IoT Edge Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azureiotedge-hub) `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-hub:<VERSION_TAG>`

2. update the image references in the deployment.template.json file for the edgeAgent and edgeHub system modules. Replace `mcr.microsoft.com` with your registry name and server for both modules.

> - edgeAgent:
>   `"image": "<registry name and server>/azureiotedge-agent:1.1",`
> - edgeHub:
>   `"image": "<registry name and server>/azureiotedge-hub:1.1",`

reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/production-checklist?view=iotedge-2020-11#store-runtime-containers-in-your-private-registry

Comment: I can't find mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-diagnostics:latest or pull on my edge device also